# `v-on:click` bind to function in module

Tags: vuejs2

I am totally new to Vuejs and my question is:

Is there anyway for `v-on` to listen on `click` event, then execute a function which is defined in a module?

For example:

```
<button v-on:click="executeClick()"></button>
```

Will execute `executeClick()` in below module, which will be imported to `Vue` instance through `require`:

```
module.exports = {
  executeClick: function () {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I am trying to keep `vue` instance's `methods` not to be crowded with a bunch of functions.

Comment: No, within the model you need features that are in this your component

Answer (score 0):

No, within the model you need features that are in this your component
soluction:

```
click.js
module.exports = {
  executeClick: function () {

  }
}

component.vue
<template>
  <tag @click="$options.click.executeClick">
</template>

<script>
import click from 'click.js'
export default {
  click: click
}
</script>
```